# java.security.properties in JNLP

Tags: java, security, applet, java-web-start

I know you ca specify a file that is going to override the java.security f

```
java -Djava.security.properties=myProperties
```

How can I set this parameter in a JNLP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties in JNLP file you can set using this tag:

```
<property name="key" value="overwritten"/>
```

But you can't set `java.security.properties` in JNLP. Not all properties are allowed to set in jnlp. For more info see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html).

Why do you need to change this property?