# Can I change disabledAlgorithms for a JWS application?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-security

Possible duplicate: [java.security.properties in JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998336/java-security-properties-in-jnlp)

We have a desktop application that we start using Java WebStart. Starting with JDK 1.8.71, *MD5 now disabled for X509 Certificate validating*. Unfortunately we cannot change the certificates we're using.

The workaround is changing the java.security file (jre/lib/security/java.security) such that "jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms" doesn't contain MD5 anymore but that's definitely out of the question since we don't have access to client computers. We tried both setting the property in the JNLP file (didn't work) and calling:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms", "");
java.security.Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "");
```

The code above works for JARs started locally but doesn't for JNLP. Any idea if this should work? I could not find any documentation as to what Security properties are editable for JNLPs.